# Возможно ли запустить отладчик pycharm без браузера?

Tags: python, django, отладка, pycharm

Можно ли как нибудь через manage.py например ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вы можете запустить любой файл с кодом питона. 
Если речь про запуск python файлов из проекта Django, то достаточно в этот файл добавить пару строчек для инициализации настроек Django.

```
import os
import django

# Добавляем в окружение переменную DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE с файлом настроек.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

# Инициализируем настройки Django
django.setup()
```

После этого, например, можно обращаться к моделям, получать данные из БД и тд и тп.

Для дебага, можете ставить breakpoint где вам нужно, и запускать этот файл прям из pycharm (правая кнопка мыши, Run %ИМЯФАЙЛА%)